# Ceiling fan has no power and an outlet in the same room- SOLVED

Tags: electrical, ceiling

I installed 4 new fan's in my upstairs bedrooms. 3 were successful with no hiccups. The fourth had a different switch and only the light turned on, the fan did not. I have also installed 2 down stairs and many before this, without issues.

I removed the light switch, which had a mess of wire caps and a jumper wire. I tried to simplify the wiring (directed by an electrician) and the fuse popped. EDITED TO ADD- I was told to separate the black and red wires that are twisted and do live black to black on the switch, red to red, then red to yellow if nothing worked and cap the rest. I tried again with no luck. I reset at the breaker box and flipped the circuit. I have a reset button on that circuit. No luck.

I got a simple, single switch with no dimmer. Power tested at the box and I have one live wire there read 120. Reset everything again and turned the power back on... light and fan still are not working. The switch has power ceiling and outlet have no power still.

I undid the wires at the fan and tested for power. There is no power! One outlet is not working. It had a small flat screen and a roku plugged into it.

There are no GFCI's blown but I reset them anyway. I'm at a loss here. Other than replacing the outlet, I'm not sure what to do.

I can't get someone to come to the house since they are not considering this urgent. I'm in military housing. (The guys also usually make this worse and I have to fix it after they leave.)!
Bottom is the outlet that is out (the only one).
[3 black (one is live) 3 white, and 1 red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZUy3.jpg)[image: 1st dial dimmer switch)][image][image][image]

Comment: If there wasn't an issue with the light before, and you hooked up the new fan/light correctly, then it seems likely that the fan/light unit was bad

Comment: It is not the fan. I definitely did my work to make sure I knew every component was working properly. I took the fan out of another room, that was working perfectly, and switched them out. There is not power coming from the wires in the ceiling. Confirmed with a meter. The outlet that was working before the fan issue also has no power to to, checked with meter to confirm. I sent my husband to get a new outlet and I'll rest everything again once it is in. I'm not sure this will fix anything but I figured it was a cheap and easy way to see if it was the issue.

Comment: @SaraDeese "*I tried to simplify the wiring*" Well that is the issue. Do you know, or did you take notes or photos of, how it was wired before you tried to simplify the wiring ?  If you can post photos of the inside of box now it may help to figure it out.

Comment: please post a picture of the wires in the outlet box. Note that I'm not an expert on wiring and probably won't attempt to answer but any 'sparkys' that come by will want the picture

Comment: I was told to do so by an electrician. I have the photo I sent him. I'll try to attach it.

Comment: Tried simplifying and the fuse popped. Sounds like a switch leg white may be a hot in this case and when you simplified the wiring it created a direct short. Now the task will be to identify where each cable comes from. Then we can get it back to functional, if you can provide a clear photo of the box and any known wires we can help you get it working again.

Comment: Yes, can you provide us with a clear photo of the inside of the box please?

Comment: @SaraDeese "*I was told to do so by an electrician*" we did not know that information. What specifically did the electrician tell you do ? To avoid this comment section running on and on resulting in it being moved, you should post **all relevant info into the body of your question**.

Comment: Great pictures but two seem to be the same, was there a fourth that you meant to post?

Comment: EDITED to add what I did with the switch that has now been changed. Duplicate copy sorry! I have tried to edit to add as much as I could. I've never posted on something like this before and I am still trying to figure it all out.

Comment: Make sure the ceiling boxes are rated/certified for ceiling fans, otherwise the vibration will tear them out of the ceiling.  You used to be able to assume if there was 3-wire cable to the switch, that meant ceiling fan was planned. But not anymore; since 2011 3-wire cable is required for essentially all switch loops.

Comment: Yes, the current fan replaced and existing fan.

Comment: How did you solve the problem?

Comment: I re-wired the switch... connected the jumper to the two black wires jumper to switch, black, that was connected to red, to other port in the switch, and bypassed the red.                                         
                                                                          Red was almost broken in half in the ceiling and broke off when I went to bypass it. It was the problem in the first place but the weak point was not visible.